# Alfresco webdav credentials issue

Tags: webclient, alfresco, webdav

We have deployed Alfresco community V5.0.d in my company.
I have to automatically mount alfresco server at startup thanks to Webdav protocol.

To do that, i’ve written a .bat file and put in on ours active directory servers : 
     net use w: /delete /yes
     net use w: \IP:8080\alfresco\webdav\Sites\test\documentLibrary/persistent:yes

I have to specify that we have 2 AD servers (without the same structure) and ours workstation are under Windows 7.

The issue is that when we type ID/Password Alfresco in the credentials prompt at startup, it doesn’t work (but it works if I access to alfreso webdav thanks to internet navigator).

I’m trying to solve this issue. 
Webclient service automatically starts. I have set the AuthForwardServerList key in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters on workstation :

- IP:8080/share
- IP:8080/alfresco
- IP:8080
- IP

It doesn't solve the problem.
Do you know how to fix this ? Can you give me some help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I blogged the details after a sucessful mounting in windows 7 & windows 2008 R2 server.
http://www.codingfreaks.net/2016/02/how-to-configure-alfresco-webdav-with.html

I thing, your mouting details are incorrect.

Incorrect : `\IP:8080\alfresco\webdav\`

**Correct** : **`\\localhost@8080\alfresco\webdav\`**

Please use the ***"@"*** symbol in between the ipaddress and the port number.